# Can't save a Pipeline estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras, pipeline

I am trying to train a simple pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
        ('deepnc', deepnc),
    ])
```

where deepnc is a Keras classifier:

```
def create_spec_model(n_col=115, density_value=2, init='normal', dropout=0.2, learning_rate=0.005, decay=0.001,
                      momentum=0.9):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dropout(dropout, input_shape=(n_col,)))
    model.add(Dense(50 * density_value, init=init, activation='relu', W_constraint=maxnorm(2),
                    W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=0, l2=1e-4)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(30 * density_value, init=init, activation='relu', W_constraint=maxnorm(2),
                    W_regularizer=l1l2(l1=0, l2=1e-4)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1, init=init, activation='sigmoid'))
    # load weights
    try:
        model.load_weights(spec_model_path)
    except:
        pass
    # Compile model
    sgd = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum, decay=decay, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I put the pipeline into a random seearch and to check some parameters:

```
deepnc = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_spec_model, validation_split=0.1, dropout=0.2, learning_rate=0.005,
                         decay=0.001, verbose=2)
# grid search epochs, batch size and optimizer
optimizers = ['adam']
init = ['uniform', 'normal']
epochs = np.array([20, 40])
batches = np.array([20, 50, 100])
learning_rate = [0.005, 0.01]
dropout = [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]
decay = [0, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01]
density_value = [1, 2, 4]
param_grid = dict(deepnc__nb_epoch=epochs, deepnc__batch_size=batches, deepnc__init=init, deepnc__dropout=dropout,
                  deepnc__learning_rate=learning_rate,
                  deepnc__density_value=density_value)
grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipeline, param_distributions=param_grid, n_iter=100, cv=5, verbose=1,
                          scoring='accuracy', fit_params={'deepnc__callbacks': [earlyStopping, modelCheck]})

grid.fit(np.array(X_train.iloc[:, :115]), y_train)
```

Afterwards, I wanted to save the best estimator and best parameters:

```
joblib.dump(grid.best_estimator_, 'models/deepn_spec_model.pkl')
joblib.dump(grid.best_params_, 'models/deepn_spec_model_best_params.pkl')
```

For some reason, the former did not work. Fortunately, I run the script in the console, so I was able to run the latter separately and save the optimal parameters. However, I am still trying to figure out how to save the model. I guess combining scikit wrapper for Keras with Pipeline and RandomizedSearchCV caused the problem?

I also tried this code:

```
path = 'models/deepn_spec_model.pkl'
pickle.dump(grid.best_estimator_, open(path, 'wb'))
```

but it generated the same error traceback. I post below a shortened version, as it was super long and consisted of repetitions of the same fragment over and over again. Googling the error did not help. Any ideas?

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 621, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 669, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 754, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function start_console_server at 0x7f0c22d08a28>: it's not found as __main__.start_console_server
```

Bonus question: Am I using the randomized search correctly? I didn't get much improvement compared to my initial effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving a Keras model wrapped inside of a Scikit classifier is not possible [GitHub Reference](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4274).

However, there is a workaround (or 2)! One is, as [Nassim Ben points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42632560/4680896), to use ModelCheckpoint to save best weights and "recreate" a model.

In my circumstances, after doing some research, I decided to do it differently, arguably easier: after training, simply do:

```
grid.best_estimator_.model.save(path)
```

This (i.e. adding .model, before saving) makes sure to access the underlying Keras model, for which the save method works correctly. Now you can simply do

```
deepnc_cont = keras.models.load_model(path)
```

And it works - at least for me :)

Note that if, for some reason, I needed to have a KerasClassifier object (the scikit wrapper), it would not work, as its contructor asks for a function that generates the model, so I would probably have to pursue Nassim's route? I'm not sure though.

Comment: I saw that .model solution somewhere but I thought it didn't work in your case, hence the "bad" hack. Cool that you found your solution to access the keras model.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot save a keras model using joblib or pickle.
Instead use the save method and shown [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model).

or in your case:

```
path = 'models/deepn_spec_model.pkl'
grid.best_estimator_.save(path)
```

and to load the model:

```
from keras.models import load_model
path = 'models/deepn_spec_model.pkl'
model = load_model(path)
```

Also note that since this is not strictly speaking a pickle file but a HDF5 file, you might as well change the file extension to '.h5'.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not as easy as that :( Actually, grid.best_estimator_ is a Pipeline object... so I guess the problem really is that Keras would like save while Pipeline would like dump, and there is no way to reconcile that?

Comment: As a workaround, you can get all the estimators from `named_steps` ('scaler' and 'deepnc' in your case) and try saving and pickling them individually through `dump` and `save`

Comment: How do you get them individually? Pipeline does not support indexing.

Comment: Call `pipeline.named_steps['deepnc'].save()` and `joblib.dump(pipeline.named_steps['deepnc'], ..path..)`. See usage of `named_steps` attribute for accessing the internal estimators.

Comment: This is just weird now... grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['deepnc'].save("models/deepn_spec_model.h5") returns "AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'save'". This is weird because I already saved models in this project like that before.

Comment: @VivekKumar in the end your approach was almost correct, one only has to make sure to first unwrap keras from the scikit wrapper and it works! Please, see my answer below for details :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what you were looking for but... Here comes nothing :

Given that your callback object has saved the best weights, you only need the model object. The model is in your function `create_spec_model()`. The only thing you need is the best parameters. So :

```
# Save parameters of the best estimator.
pickle.dump(grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['deepnc'].get_params(),open('params.pkl','wb'))
```

At loading time, given that your function `create_spec_model()` is still in your code :

```
import inspect

def load_model(params_path, weights_path):
    params = pickle.load(open(params_path,'rb'))
    params = {k: params[k] for k in inspect.getargspec(create_spec_model)[0] if k in params.keys()}
    model = create_spec_model(**params)
    model.load_weights(weights_path)
    return model
```

does that help you?

Comment: I give an upvote because it works and for effort, however, there is, in my humble opinion, an even better way to do it, which I'll post in a moment :)

Comment: Cool, can't wait to see it!

Comment: Well, it's here :)
Since you already invested in researching this problem, please let me know what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another workaround for the Keras-Pickle problem.

It's a bit patchy, but allows Keras models to be stored with `pickle` so  it works for both the Model and containing objects.

http://zachmoshe.com/2017/04/03/pickling-keras-models.html